# How to "manually fix this package" (aptitude error)?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

Whenever I try to `aptitude install` something I get this error:

```
E: I wasn't able to locate a file for the libxmlrpc-c3 package. 
This might   mean you need to manually fix this package. (due to missing arch)
Writing extended state information... Done
E: I wasn't able to locate a file for the libxmlrpc-c3 package. 
This might   mean you need to manually fix this package. (due to missing arch)
E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download
```

I `aptitude remove`d and deleted the package from `/var/cache/apt/archive`, but get the same error when I try again.

This is the from dpkg/status:

```
Package: libxmlrpc-c3
Status: deinstall reinstreq half-installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Version: 1.06.27-1.1
```

This is the from `lsb_release -a; uname -a; dpkg-architecture; apt-cache policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer`:

```
DEB_BUILD_ARCH=i386
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=i386
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=32
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=i486
DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=i486-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_ARCH=i386
DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=i386
DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=32
DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=i486
DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=i486-linux-gnu
ttf-mscorefonts-installer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7
  Version table:
     2.7 0
        500 http://ftp.cn.debian.org lenny/contrib Packages
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dpkg` man page has

> PACKAGE FLAGS
>          reinst-required
>                 A package marked reinst-required  is  broken  and  requires    reinstallation.  These  packages  cannot  be  removed, 
>   unless  forced  with  option
>                 --force-remove-reinstreq.

So try

```
dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove libxmlrpc-c3
```

Alternatively, you can use `--purge` instead of `--remove` if you want to remove the configuration files as well, since `--remove` won't remove them.

Comment: it worked and I learned something new

Comment: I also had to `--purge` the problematic package for `install` to work again.